# Highcharts boxplot line rendering issues: is there a solution?

Tags: highcharts, rendering, boxplot

Using the new Highcharts 3 boxplot series type, in Firefox, there are some significant issues with the line rendering.

The issue is visible on the Highcharts demo page: 
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fWN75/

```
chart: {
     type: 'boxplot'
}
```

Issues appear to be

1) median line is drawn beyond the containing box by a few pixels

2) whisker lines are drawn into the box by a few pixels, especially on the lower end

3) whisker lines extend beyond end lines by a few pixels occasionally, especially on the 
lower end

The question(s):

1) is this a known issue?

2) is there a solution?

So far I do not see this issue in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I've reported it to our devs here:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1638

Thanks you for suggestion